# How many times can tag an image for Alchemy API?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, alchemy

I would like to ask you about Alchemy API on Bluemix. Using Achemy API, how many times can you tag an image?

Is it only twice times?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/03/04/ibm-acquires-alchemyapi/), on March IBM announced the acquisition of AlchemyAPI and it integrated AlchemyAPI’s deep learning technology with the Watson platform exposing these capabilities to the developer community through IBM Bluemix.
For this reason AlchemyAPI on Bluemix has basically the same features that it had before. That means that you have a certain number of REST API calls included in your plan.

Bluemix provides the following plans:

- *IBM AlchemyAPI Free Plan*: with 1.000 API Events per day per Bluemix Organization
- *IBM AlchemyAPI Standard*: pay per use plan in which you will be charged per API Event.

Among the REST APIs you need the [*AlchemyVision*](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/image-tagging/proc.html) ones to tag images, and you can use them all the times you need. All you need is an API key, that is obtained after choosing a plan.